# when does factory girl create objects in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda, factory-bot

I am trying to simulate a session using `FactoryGirl`/`shoulda` (it worked with fixtures but i am having problems with using factories). I have following factories (user login and email both have `unique` validations):

```
Factory.define :user do |u| 
 u.login 'quentin'
 u.email 'quentin@example.com'
end

Factory.define :session_user, :class => Session do |ses| 
 ses.association :user, :factory => :user
 ses.session_id 'session_user'
end
```

and here's the test

```
class MessagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

 context "normal user" do
  setup do 
   @request.session[:user_id]=Factory(:user).id
   @request.session[:session_id]=Factory(:session_user).session_id
  end

  should "be able to access new message creation" do
   get :new
   assert_response :success
  end
 end
end
```

but when i run `rake test:functionals`, I get this test result

```
 1) Error: 
  test: normal user should be able to access new message creation. (MessagesControllerTest):
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Account name already exists!, Email already exists!
```

which means that record already exists in db when I am referring to it in the test setup. Is there something I don't understand here? does `FactoryGirl` create all factories in db on startup?

rails 2.3.5/shoulda/FactoryGirl

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Factory(:user)` is a shortcut for `Factory.create(:user)` so within your setup you are creating two objects and saving them to the database.

`Factory.build(:user)` will create you a `user` record without saving it to the DB.

**EDIT**

Within your `session_user` factory you are creating a user and then creating another within your test setup. `FactoryGirl` will create a new `user` record because you have the association in the `session_user` factory.

You can either get your `user` instance from the `session_user` object as follows :-

```
 context "normal user" do
  setup do
   session = Factory(:session_user)  
   @request.session[:session_id] = session.session_id
   @request.session[:user_id] = session.user_id
  end
```

or you can add some details to the `user` factory to ensure unique name and email addresses as follows :-

```
Factory.define :user do |u| 
 u.sequence(:login) {|n| "quentin#{n}" }
 u.sequence(:email) {|n| "quentin#{n}@example.com"}
end
```

Comment: but i have only one Factory(:user) mention in my code. why does it run twice? (second is Factory(:session_user), which is a Session instance)